# Suspect loadByUsername call on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, security, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Spring Boot application deployed on ElasticBeanstalk. I'm about to start beta tests, so there are no so many people that know application url yet. Yesterday I found out in log file that someone called `loadByUsername` method from my implementation of `UserDetailsService`. The point is that there is no any other log at this time. If this user would try to log in I would find information about login method call and `Authentication Success/Fail Handler`. So I'm assuming that this user have used some Spring or Tomcat vulnerability. So there are 2 questions:

1. how it's possible that someone has guess my url (domain or CloudFront url)? Are pople use bots to scan CloudFront urls with brute-force method?
2. how this person has called loadByUsername method without calling authentication handlers? Is there a known vulnerability in Spring? Or someone has injected some malware? How to protect it?

I use Spring Boot 1.5.8. I think it's good to mention that couple days ago I found in logs that someone tried to call some universal names like phpMyAdmin, /api/admin, wp-admin and so on. And in all cases server returned 404.

```
public class UserDetailsManager implements UserDetailsService  {

    @Autowired
    private static final Logger LOG;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOG.debug("Load by username: {}", login);
        return userDao.getByLogin(login).map(user -> new CustomUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for login " + login));
    }

}
```

**edit**:
I found out if user doesn't use Spring Security /login enpoint to authenticate, but call any protected url wit basic auth, Spring ommits Authentication handlers. That's why there were no any other logs.
In nginx logs I found call from this `User-Agent`: `https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan`. So now the only question is how some random people know about my website? Is there any registry of newly created Cloudfront urls?

Comment: "I'm assuming that this user have used some Spring or Tomcat vulnerability": possible, but so vanishingly small that you should look at your own code first.

Comment: If you have access logs, you should be able to correlate the call to this service method with the IP address of the user that made the call.

Comment: I found out the reason of this application behavious (in post edit). I know IP of this user from logs. But what can I do with this knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

> So now the only question is how some random people know about my website? Is there any registry of newly created Cloudfront urls?

No, but the address ranges used by Amazon are well known, and if you had gone to the GitHub project identified by the user agent, you would see this:

> TCP port scanner, spews SYN packets asynchronously, scanning entire Internet in under 5 minutes.

So in other words, some script kiddie was probing your site.

Your *real* question should be "What controller on my site called this service method, and what URL triggered that controller?" But that's something that only you can answer, because only you know the structure of your site.

However, there's one more thing:

> I found out if user doesn't use Spring Security /login enpoint to authenticate, but call any protected url wit basic auth, Spring ommits Authentication handlers.

*Authentication* is only the first step in securing your site. *Authorization* is the second and more important part, and it looks like you haven't implemented that.

Comment: _"Authentication is only the first step in securing your site. Authorization is the second and more important part, and it looks like you haven't implemented that."_

I have both already. The problem was that in configuration I allowed to call http basic authentication. So when I turn it off problem is solved.

_"No, but the address ranges used by Amazon are well known"_
Ok, so someone is scaning all websites randomly by ip. I thought someone want to break my application. Thank you for you answer.